# Why do I get this error and how do I bypass it? (powershell & python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, powershell, operating-system, system-administration

I have a bunch of other commands with multiple arguments, but python doesnt seem to like this one. Any help would be appreciated. The command runs no problem in powershell. I tried all sorts of combinations with ', ", "" to get it to work

```
'''subprocess.run("""powershell.exe Get-Service -Name 'Remote Desktop Services' ""Remote Desktop Configuration"", 'Remote Desktop Services UserMode Port Redirector'""", shell=True, text=True)'''
```

the command that works in powerhell

```
''' Get-Service -Name "Remote Desktop Services", "Remote Desktop Configuration", "Remote Desktop Services UserMode Port Redirector"'''
```

output

```
'''Get-Service : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'Desktop'. At line:1 char:1 + Get-Service -Name 'Remote Desktop Services', Remote Desktop Configura +
```

CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-Service], ParameterBindingException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetServiceCommand '''

Answer (score 0):

```
def run(self, cmd):
    completed = subprocess.run(["powershell", "-Command", cmd], capture_output=True)
    return completed
```

this should do the job

Comment: nope not for me. Can you try putting in the whole command ? as theres 3 sets of "" and thats where the problem lies. When I do what you did it just does nothing

Comment: Do you mean like this? `'''subprocess.run("""powershell -Command Get-Service -Name 'Remote Desktop Services' ""Remote Desktop Configuration"", 'Remote Desktop Services UserMode Port Redirector'""", shell=True, text=True)'''`

Comment: So this is what I am trying, the output both on terminal and the output is empty
   ' ' '     with open('output3.txt', 'w') as f:
    def run(self, cmd):
        completed = subprocess.run("""powershell -Command Get-Service -Name 'Remote Desktop Services' ""Remote Desktop Configuration"", 'Remote Desktop Services UserMode Port Redirector'""",stdout=f, shell=True, text=True)
        print(completed, file=f)
' ' '

Comment: can you post your whole code?

Comment: That is the whole code. I want the output from this command into a text file. For some reason it doesnt want to trigger the code block with '''

Comment: Code blocks inside ''' are, i think, treated as a multiline comment in pyton3 (https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_comments.asp)